# Редирект в .htaccess https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

```html
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2017 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems with some server configurations.
# It is required for the use of mod_rewrite, but it may have already been set by your
# server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in this .htaccess file.
# If using it causes your site to produce an error, comment it out (add # to the
# beginning of the line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef urls. If
# they work, then it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need to
# set it here.
##

## No directory listings
<IfModule autoindex>
  IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
#Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.html?$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
#RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Убирает маски  /m/ и /mobile/
#RewriteRule ^mobile/(.+)$ https://didzher.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^m/(.+)$ https://didzher.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.didzher\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://didzher.com/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
# 30 дней
<filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>

#<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
#</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>


## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site then comment out the operations listed
# below by adding a # to the beginning of the line.
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` on Joomla!
#
# Block any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root home page
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment the following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !administrator
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^skidki-i-aktsii/akciya-%C2%ABzakazhite-shater-ot-300m2-i-poluchite-osveshhenie-v-podarok%C2%BB$ skidki-i-aktsii/akciya-zakazhite-shater-ot-300m2-i-poluchite-osveshhenie-v-podarok/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^skidki-i-aktsii/akciya-«zakazhite-shater-ot-300m2-i-poluchite-osveshhenie-v-podarok»$ skidki-i-aktsii/akciya-zakazhite-shater-ot-300m2-i-poluchite-osveshhenie-v-podarok/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^skidki-i-aktsii/akciya-%C2%ABzakazhite-shater-ot-60-m2-i-poluchite-skidku-na-speceffekty-25-%C2%BB$ skidki-i-aktsii/akciya-zakazhite-shater-ot-60-m2-i-poluchite-skidku-na-speceffekty-25/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^skidki-i-aktsii/akciya-«zakazhite-shater-ot-60-m2-i-poluchite-skidku-na-speceffekty-25-»$ skidki-i-aktsii/akciya-zakazhite-shater-ot-60-m2-i-poluchite-skidku-na-speceffekty-25/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^skidki-i-aktsii/akciya-%C2%AB5-tentov-pagoda-v-arendu-po-cene-4-h%C2%BB$ skidki-i-aktsii/akciya-5-tentov-pagoda-v-arendu-po-cene-4-h/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^skidki-i-aktsii/akciya-«5-tentov-pagoda-v-arendu-po-cene-4-h»$ skidki-i-aktsii/akciya-5-tentov-pagoda-v-arendu-po-cene-4-h/ [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^about.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^about_en.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/item/tyazhelyj-dym-na-prezentacii-kia-quoris-na-avtosalone-sia$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^spetseffekty/nestandartnye-speceffecty/item/sbros-tkani$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^tentovye-konstruktsii$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fire_effects.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^novosti/item/uglekislotnye-fontany-aerostrim-jetco2-na-koncerte-dzidzio$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^novosti/item/speceffekty-scenicheskaya-pirotehnika-fejerverki-k-novomu-godu$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^novosti/item/sistema-sbrosa-zanavesa-na-prezentacii-an-178$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^novosti/item/interaktivnaya-prezentaciya-multimedijnogo-shou-tehnologiya-emocij-v-ekspoplaze-2$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^aerostreem.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^skidki-i-aktsii/item/skidka-na-novogodnie-speceffekty$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^arenda-shatrov/item/arenda-aksesuarov$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/item/bumazhnoe-shou$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^news.php/42$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^novosti/43-spetseffekty-na-shou-golos-strany-4-perezagruzka$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^speceffects.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^partnery/? / [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^novosti/item/novogodnyaya-tehnologiya-emocij$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^waterscreen.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^spetseffekty/item/aerofontany-2$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fogscreen.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^novosti/item/graficheskij-vodnyj-ekran-na-vystavke$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^novosti/item/novogodnyaya-territoriya-emocij-ploshhadka-vashej-mechty$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^o-kompanii$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^skidki-i-aktsii/item/skidka-30-na-pnevmozvezdy-i-pnevmokonusa-2$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^spetseffekty/vodnye-effekty/item/sbros-tkani$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^bigblaster.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^arenda-shatrov/item/obogrevkondicionirovanie$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/item/aerofontany$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^arenda-shatrov/item/polkovrolin$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^novosti/item/letayushhaya-tkan-na-turkvision-2014$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^novosti/item/interaktivnaya-prezentaciya-multimedijnogo-shou-tehnologiya-emocij$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^novosti/item/priznanie-v-lyubvi$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^imitation_fire.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^novosti/item/tenty-unifleks-na-7-m-festivale-ulichnoj-edy$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^spetseffekty/nestandartnye-speceffecty/item/sistema-sbrosa-tkani-power-drop$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/item/dozhd-iz-konfetti-na-pokaze-yuvelirnogo-doma-zarina$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^tentovye-konstruktsii/tent-pagoda$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^novosti/item/s-prazdnikom-vesny-3$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^8-russkij-yazyk/novosti/41-spetseffekty-na-tantsevalnom-shou-strasti-na-parkete$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^8-russkij-yazyk/novosti/14-nasha-novinka-ruchnaya-pushka-dlya-krioeffektov-magicfx-co2-gun$ https://didzher.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^9-russkij-yazyk/publikatsii$ https://didzher.com/  [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^skidki-i-aktsii/item/akciya-%C2%ABzakazhite-shater-ot-300m2-i-poluchite-osveshhenie-v-podarok%C2%BB$ https://didzher.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^skidki-i-aktsii/item/akciya-«zakazhite-shater-ot-300m2-i-poluchite-osveshhenie-v-podarok»$ https://didzher.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^home/8-russkij-yazyk/novosti/14-nasha-novinka-ruchnaya-pushka-dlya-krioeffektov-magicfx-co2-gun$ https://didzher.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^home/9-russkij-yazyk/publikatsii$ https://didzher.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^skidki-i-aktsii/akciya$ skidki-i-aktsii/akciya-zakazhite-shater-ot-300m2-i-poluchite-osveshhenie-v-podarok/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
#RewriteRule ^spetseffekty/nestandartnye-speceffecty/aerofontany$ https://didzher.com/spetseffekty/nestandartnye-speceffecty/aerofontany-2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
#RewriteRule ^arenda-shatrov/obogrevkondicionirovanie$ https://didzher.com/arenda-shatrov/dopolnitelnye-uslugi/arenda-obogrevatelej [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
#RewriteRule ^arenda-shatrov/polkovrolin$ https://didzher.com/arenda-shatrov/dopolnitelnye-uslugi/arenda-kovrolina [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
#RewriteRule ^arenda-shatrov/arenda-aksesuarov$ https://didzher.com/arenda-shatrov/dopolnitelnye-uslugi/arenda-prezentacionnogo-oborudovanija [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
#RewriteRule ^nestandartnye-spetseffekty$ https://didzher.com/spetseffekty  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^didzher\.com\.ua$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.didzher\.com\.ua$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/didzher\.com\/" [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /nestandartnye-spetseffekty /spetseffekty

Redirect 301 /portfolio/krug-dozhdya-na-shou-«-hochu-v-via-gru» https://didzher.com/portfolio/krug-dozhdya-na-shou-hochu-v-via-gru

Redirect 301 /portfolio/piromuzykalnoe-shou-«super-mts-tur-20-let-vmeste» https://didzher.com/portfolio/piromuzykalnoe-shou-super-mts-tur-20-let-vmeste
```

Помогите настроить редирект со страницы https://didzher.com/index.html на https://didzher.com в.htaccess.
Этот код не работает `Redirect 301 /index.html https://didzher.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сегодня этот вопрос был решен следующим образом:

1. Я понял по настройкам хостинга, что файл index.html является статическим.
2. Добавил html в исполняемые файлы PHP. Было так: "PHP файлы: php". Стало так: "PHP файлы: php,html". Теперь в файле index.html начал обрабатываться php-код.
3. В данный файл я добавил следующие строки:

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.html') {
       header('Location: https://didzher.com',TRUE,301);
       exit();
   }

Теперь редирект работает на 100%. Другие решения - нет.
Надеюсь, что кому-то это поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Ничего сложного, попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.html?$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

> UPD

Если сайт работает на `Joomla!` вам ничего трогать в `.htaccess` не нужно, надо просто активировать `Use URL Rewriting` как указано на скрине:
 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тоже не работает, сайт на joomla. Пробовал настраивать редирект на других ресурсах - работает. А на этом - нет.

Comment: @АлександрЛипухин , обновил ответ, надеюсь в данном CMS до вас никто, ничего  нестандартного не делал ))  (переделки)

Comment: делали, в том то все и дело.

Comment: А Ваш код нужно вставлять до `RewriteBase /` ил после?

Comment: @АлександрЛипухин   Вы можете вставить весь код из htaccess в  вопрос, чтобы не гадать что у вас там сделано. В админке Use URL Rewriting активирован ?

Comment: добавил код. Его очень много.

Comment: @АлександрЛипухин удалите после RewriteEngine On - --  #RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^index.html$ https://didzher.com [R=301,L]  и поставьте мой пример

Comment: Добавил, в корне лежит файл index.html и его всеравно выдает(((((

Comment: это прямо фантастика какая-то

Comment: минуточку, как это " в корне лежит файл index.htm" ? т.е в корне сайта есть html файл и при заходе на сайт открывается файл index.html ?

Comment: да, если четко указать путь https://didzher.com/index.html, то он откроется. Там же есть и index.php CMS

Comment: так, я закомментировал index.html. И перенаправление заработало. Обясните, а почему с файлом не работало перенаправление?

Comment: @АлександрЛипухин вы изначально очень некорректно задали вопрос о вашей проблеме,  конечно если в root сервера находится index.html то это для сервера преоритетней и браузер открывает в первую очередь этот файл, а ваш index.php не активируется!!!!! вам надо удали этот файл index.html или переименовать!!

Comment: Ссылка https://didzher.com/ запускает index.php нормально. Просто там был и файл index.html. А в задаче у меня стояло " Настроить редиректы со страницы https://didzher.com/index.html на https://didzher.com"

Comment: Помогите мне пожалуйста настроить редиректы со страницы https://didzher.com/index.html на https://didzher.com